# UIBARBUTTON back action

Tags: ios, swift

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: Selector(("HomeTabController")))

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

The above code is the creation of button in `navigationController` but I can create a button cannot write a specific view controller to open.

I have tried with `popViewController` and `popToRootViewController` action, need a specific code for opening a particular `viewController` in swift, with the help of the particular `viewController` storyboard id and viewcontrollername.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add func name in `#selctor()` (Swift 4 version)

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goToViewController(_:)))

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

You need to create a func.

```
@objc func goToViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    //write code here to open a view controller

    let storyboard = "Main"
    let viewControllerIdentifier = "HomeVC"
    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerIdentifier) as! HomeVC
    //push/present "viewController"
}
```

Comment: let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gotoHome") as? HomeTabController. does this code will be effective

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: I need the exact code to be written inside the function inorder to open up a view controller @Mahendra GP

Comment: Haha...exact code...Its a helping community, not paid one...so its better to try something by yourself also.:)

Answer (score 0):

in this code just replace ChatVC name to your viewcontroller name

```
@objc func goToViewController(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
                if controller.isKind(of: ChatVC.self) {
                    self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                    break
                } else {
                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
            }
}
```